# ¿Funciones no declaradas?

Tags: c++

Tengo estas 3 funciones que uso para cambiar los colores de mi programa:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void color_correcto()
system ("color 4a");
}
void color_error()
{
system ("color 4e");
} 
void color_original()
{
system ("color 4f");
}
```

Ellas están declaradas en un Header llamado "Funciones.h". Mi problema es cuando voy a otro header (Llamemoslo Test), en el debería incluir Funciones.h si yo quisiese usar las funciones de que declare dentro de el, ¿Verdad?:

```
#include "Funciones.h"

color_correcto();
color_error();
color_original();
```

El main quedaría asi:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Funciones.h"
#include "Test.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main ()

{

color_correcto();
color_error();
color_original();

 return 0;
}
```

Bueno, cuando hago esto y compilo me sale un error diciendo que estas funciones no fueron declaradas en el header Test, a pesar de que le incluí el header "Funciones.h" de antemano .¿Alguien sabe cual podría ser el problema?

Answer (score 1):

C++ no entiende de formatos de ficheros. Lo que sucede es que para intentar reducir la confusión se ha tomado como costumbre que los ficheros de cabecera tengan la extensión `.h` o `.hpp` y los ficheros de código `.c` o `.cpp`.

En los ficheros de cabecera debe incluirse la declaración de funciones y clases que vayan a ser *públicas*, es decir, aquellas que vayan a utilizarse en diferentes partes de la aplicación (para empezar asume que todas son de este tipo). y en los ficheros de código o implementación se suele poner la implementación de dichas funciones y clases.

Entonces tu código debería estar estructurado así:

Funciones.h

```
// Esto es una guarda, ya entenderás su función más adelante.
#ifndef FUNCIONES_H
#define FUNCIONES_H

color_correcto();
color_error();
color_original();

#endif
```

Funciones.c

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "funciones.h"

void color_correcto()
{ // Te falta esta llave en tu codigo
  system ("color 4a");
}

void color_error()
{
  system ("color 4e");
} 
void color_original()
{
  system ("color 4f");
}
```

Con estos cambios ya debería funcionarte tu programa... aunque si no imprimes nada en la consola no creo que puedas verificar si funcionan los comandos o no.

Answer (score 0):

Lo haces al revés, en el `.h` van las declaraciones de funciones (sin la implementación, solo acabadas en el `;`) y en el `.c` la definición (con la implementación)

Una declaración o una definición de una función incluye el tipo que devuelven (o `void` si no devuelven nada). Como les falta, el compilador intenta interpretar el código, y piensa que son invocaciones a dichas funciones, en vez de su declaración.

```
int color_correcto();
int color_error();
void color_original();
```

o como toque.

Y, en otro orden de cosas, en C no hay codigo "suelto" como pueda haber en Javascript o PHP. Todo debe ser parte de una función (la función inicial es `main`).

Comment: Es que eso es lo que quiero hacer. yo no quiero volver a declarar las funciones en otro header, yo quiero invocarlas desde Funciones.h y ahí es cuando me da problemas

Comment: Los `.h` están para declaraciones, el código va en los `.c`. Cuando alguien tiene que usar tu librería, le pasas los `.h` junto con los binarios compilados y así puede usar tus funciones sin ver tu código fuente, que está en los `.c`. Incluso ignorando eso, no se puede hacer lo que tu dices, ya que lo primero que incluyes en el `.c` será el `include`; el compilador pasará a tratar el  `.h` y se encontrará con una llamada a una función que, llegados a ese punto, no está definida.

Comment: Y, para terminar, todo el código a ejecutar está dentro de funciones (incluyendo `main`). Aún solucionando lo de las declaraciones y todo lo demás, tendrías un fallo de compilación por eso.